# openssl and ruby certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, activemerchant

I'm getting a certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError) error.

- ubuntu 12.04
- ruby 1.9.3
- openssl installed via rvm

This command works ok

> openssl s_client -CAfile ./ccapi.pem -connect ccapi.client.qvalent.com:443

=>  `Verify return code: 0 (ok)`

Running a ruby script using activemerchant that calls out to the above site using same pem file

```
ruby pwtest.rb
```

=>

```
credit card is valid!
/home/rzolkos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

The script works fine on another server/local machine.

Any tips on fixing or diagnosing appreciated.